# My android emulator doesnt launch

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I installed the Android Development Tool and created my first app but when I run the app, the emulator doesnt launch.The console reads:

```
    [2013-06-18 14:36:57 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
    [2013-06-18 14:36:57 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
    [2013-06-18 14:36:57 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
    [2013-06-18 14:37:19 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD'
```

Unfortunately, it never launches. The following is what I have tried to do to solve the problem:

1. I created AVD both by graphical user interface and command line but it didnt run.
2. I tried to open task manager and stop the adb.exe process then run it again but no.
3. I tried to kill the adb server and restart it by command line but again no, didnt run.
4. I finally tried to launch the emulator on command line and this is what it says (directly translated): "a problem interrupted the program, trouble-free operation. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution to the problem is available."

Please help.

Comment: how much ram do you have set for your emulator? It often crashes before launch under windows if setting more than 512 MB

Comment: How do you check the ram size set for the emulator? At the bottom of the window, I can see something like Heap size: 60M of 200M. Is it the one?

Comment: No, that is the RAM used by your Eclipse. I have marked the setting in [this image](http://imgur.com/POMkGpk) for you. It's in the "edit" or "create" dialog of the AVD Manager

Comment: Ok, the RAM is set at 343.

Comment: But it still doesnt run.

Comment: I'm sorry then I don't know an immediate/generally applicable solution. You'll have to post a screenshot of your emulator settings, the full command line output...

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle, I decided to install a new Operating System. The emulator can now launch.